# blank screen on xrdp

Tags: pi-3

xrdp is working up to and until today. I have today "sudo apt-get upgrade" and since then xrdp has stopped working. The login screen comes up but when i get in it is just a blank screen (the aqua one). The only thing I can do is close the screen down.

I have looked through the other solutions but nothing has worked.

I have a raspberry pi 3 running raspbian - which is headless.

Anyone know why?

Comment: did you call `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Yeah- just tried it again (update and then upgrade) and the screen is still blank. Used Windows Remote Connection on laptop and Microsoft Desktop on iPhone and the desktop is blank on both

Comment: same here, don't know why and haven't found a fix.
raspbian 2018-04-18 doesn't fix it.
my current "fix" is to use an image from 2017-09 and NOT update/upgrade